# How to register unique app name in playstore account?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to register android application name unique in playstore.i will put apk after 2 month so is it possible  to take unique name in playstore?so another can not take that particular name.please help me advance in thanks.

Comment: No, its not possible. (reason: If its there then everyone can reserve the name but what if they not able to upload apk later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. In `Android` market uniqueness is based on the package name of your Application while publishing in `Google Play`, not based on App Name. Your Application's Package Name must be unique.